# Jordan double border crossing?

Tags: visas, israel, jordan, middle-east, palestine

We will soon be flying into Jordan (from Canada). During our 2 weeks there, we will cross into the West Bank (Palestine/Israel). We will then go back into Jordan for our return flight.  Should we buy the 2-entry visa for 60JOD as per [wiki travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Jordan#Visa)?  Is the land crossing count the same as the air entry?

Comment: Since the West Bank is not Jordan, you will be entering Jordan twice. Common sense tells me you’ll need two visas, one for each entry. I’m not familiar enough with the exact procedures to provide an answer, though.

Comment: Common sense is sometimes wrong. I suggest you inquire of the Jordanian Embassy, because this tour operator says you may re-enter via the Allenby Bridge if you left by the bridge, provided your visa is still valid in duration, not number of entries. http://www.amman2jerusalem.com/passport-and-visa-faqs

Comment: @Jan It's not that straightforward: despite the peace treaty, Jordan still has not relinquished its claim on the West Bank, and neither has Israel fully annexed it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel%E2%80%93Jordan_peace_treaty#Content

Comment: If you intend to leave Israel through the Allenby bridge, note these requirements: `​Crossing the border at the terminal requires a valid passport with an expiration date at least six months after the departure date and all required documents for exiting:
Entry visa to Jordan clearly stating that the crossing is through the Allenby Border Terminal.` [Source here](http://www.iaa.gov.il/en-us/borders/alenbi/pages/default.aspx).

Comment: @jpatokal I believe this is also why you cannot get a Jordanian visa-on-arrival at the Allenby Bridge crossing. The legal fiction is that the West Bank is part of Jordan, so why would you need a visa "on arrival" if you were, like, y'know, *already in Jordan*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may depend on which crossing you will use. If you go by the Allenby bridge, and return by the Allenby bridge within the visa validity, you don't need a multiple entry visa. They also do not make any stamp on your passport on the Jordanian side (and you can ask for no stamp on the Israeli side) at this border crossing.

From a [much older version](http://wikitravel.org/wiki/en/index.php?title=Jordan&oldid=1813495) of the same Wikitravel page:

> If you leave Jordan at the Allenby/King Hussein bridge crossing with Israel, then return while the visa is still valid so that you do not need to buy a new one. This is because West Bank is recognized by Jordan as a part of Jordan.

I did this in 2011, although looking at my passport it does appear that I paid 20 JD for an arrival visa, so I'm slightly puzzled as to whether I bought a multiple entry as that was the cost at the time per Wikitravel.

Since I assume you will be purchasing an arrival visa, you can probably just ask the immigration official to confirm whether leaving and returing via Allenby is multiple entries.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! I wanted to buy the Jordan pass that includes the Visa so this definitely helps.