# Visa requirements for leaving Israel, going to Jordan, returning to Israel again

Tags: israel, jordan

I am a UK citizen heading to Israel and Jordan in April. My concern is to do with border crossings / visa stuff.

Here is my plan:

1. Arrive in Tel Aviv from UK (visa on arrival)
2. Enter Jordan via The Jordan River Crossing (Nazareth to Amman)
3. Travel around Jordan for 4 days
4. Re-enter Israel (preferably via Allenby Bridge / King Hussein Bridge)
5. Travel around Israel
6. Fly back to UK from Israel

My questions are:

- Can I do step number 4: can I re-enter Israel after leaving for just 4 days?
- If yes, do I need to purchase a new visa?
- If yes, can I re-enter via the Allenby Bridge?

I can't quite find the answer to this anywhere (even after much forum searching and on here!) It seems like the situation is pretty volatile and subject to sudden changes.

This similar question here is about going the other direction (Jordan --> Israel --> Jordan). 
[Jordan double border crossing?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95549/jordan-double-border-crossing/)

Comment: Can you even get back into Jordan with travel to Israel?

Comment: @Matthew yes, Jordan and Israel have a treaty and diplomatic relations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two unlikely but possible problems. First, if your total stay in Israel will exceed six months or whatever unusual shorter period you get on your initial entry, there may be an issue with the length. It sounds, however, as if Step One is a few days or weeks for tourism, in which case this is a non-issue. Second, the Allenby Bridge crossing is a [pain in the neck](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293985-i2131-k3180262-Crossing_King_Hussein_Bridge_Allenby_Bridge_in_Jordan_Israel-Jordan.html) compared to either the Jordan River Crossing or the Aqaba Crossing.

Many tourists do something like your itinerary, to include Petra or other Jordanian sites in a trip to Israel. Speaking of which, I recommend Petra very highly.

Comment: thanks for your answer! So basically just to summarise: I will be able to re-enter Israel on the same visa? And should I chose, I can travel back along the Allenby Bridge?

Comment: Not the same visa. If you are British, you are just getting admitted on arrival, no advance visa required. You'll be readmites with a new entry form, but it won't be an issue other than the annoying queue.